# Why is my float displayed as 0 in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

One of my columns `process_size` holds a value `800089856` in `bytes`.

My SQL query says

```
select ((process_size*11/(1024*1024*1024))*100)/(4*3600) as Avg_wk_sum from instances where wk_id = 2
```

But instead of a float value it shows `0`.

I even tried explicit cast

```
select ((process_size*11/(1024*1024*1024))*100)/(4*3600) :: float as Avg_wk_sum from instances where wk_id = 2
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the float value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All values in your statement are integers, so the actual division/multiplication is carried out using integers - which yields 0. You then cast the *result* (`0`)  to a float which doesn't change anything.

You should cast `process_size` to a float, then all subsequent operations are carried out using floats.

```
select ((process_size::float*11/(1024*1024*1024))*100)/(4*3600)
```

However if you care about precise results, you should stay away from approximate data types like float and use `numeric` instead.

Comment: Float works. But if try `process_size::numeric * 11..` it again comes back to 0. How to use the same?

Comment: @StrugglingCoder: `::numeric` works for me: http://rextester.com/YDECO92680